# Send data from SQL server to InfluxDB via Apache Nifi's PutInfluxDB processor

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb

I've been trying to send data from SQL server to InfluxDB via Apache Nifi's PutInfluxDB processor. I have used these processors in sequence: ExecuteSQL, ConvertRecord (from AvroReader to CsvWriter), PutInfluxDB, and LogAttribute.[Nifi Flow Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKTgI.png) The processors upto ConvertRecord work fine but then PutInfluxDB shows this error message: "All Nodes - Error PutInfluxDB[id=blahblah] failed to insert into influxDB due to {"code":"unauthorized", "message":"unauthorized"}:org.influxdb.InfluxDBException:{"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized"}[PutInfluxDB config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGpXR.png)

Please help me solve this. Thanks!

This is the error I get when I try creating auth for a user [Error with auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFuJ5.png).

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your PutInfluxDB config. Are you providing credentials for a user that has Write access to the table?

Comment: I've updated the question to add the screenshot of PutInfluxDB config. Yes, I'm providing admin credentials and admin has write access to the table. I am using Nifi-1.13.2_alpine and InfluxDB-2.1.1_alpine. From what I've read so far, 2.1.1 authenticates via Token only, not username and password and Nifi 1.13.2 UI doesn't have a Token property. Could this be the cause of the problem? If yes, could you please suggest me a solution? Also, I've deployed this setup as a docker container.

Comment: Looks like you need to set specific v1 compatible user/passwords in Influx? https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/upgrade/v1-to-v2/manual-upgrade/#1x-compatible-authorizations - Alternatively, you could look at the InfluxDB Nars from InfluxData here https://github.com/influxdata/nifi-influxdb-bundle which has a PutInfluxDatabase_2 processor that should have Token auth

Comment: I've added the screenshot in the question for when I try to create authorization in the way you mentioned. This error has persisted for a long time.

Comment: Here's another thread discussing v1 client auth on InfluxDB2 https://community.influxdata.com/t/getting-started-with-influxdb-docker-401-unauthorized/16989/4 you either need to configure this in Influx, or switch to using the PutInfluxDatabase_2 processor I linked before and use the v2 tokens.

Comment: I tried configuring client auth but that didn't seem to help. Seems like updating Nifi lib to use PutInfluxDatabase_2 processor is the only option. Could you please also help me out with a proper Nifi flow for writing data from SQL server to InfluxDB because when I tried the same via Rest API, InfluxDB did not accept the CSV Record or the JSON format data? Please direct me to a correct Nifi flow

Answer (score 1):

The issue your experiencing is because you're attempting to write to InfluxDB 2.x and the PutInfluxDB processor included with NiFi is only compatible with InfluxDB 1.x.

InfluxData has NiFi plugins available to support InfluxDB 2.x: https://github.com/influxdata/nifi-influxdb-bundle

After installing the plugins, the processor you'll want to use is called `PutInfluxDatabaseRecord_2`.

To install the plugin, simply download the nar file for your version of NiFi (I believe it's 1.13.x in your case) and copy the file to the `lib` folder of your NiFi deployment:

e.g. `$ cp ~/Downloads/nifi-influx-database-nar-1.13.0.nar $NIFI_HOME/lib`

When you restart NiFi, the `PutInfluxDatabaseRecord_2` processor will be available. This processor requires a `StandardInfluxDatabaseService_2` controller service which is where you will configure access to InfluxDB via an InfluxDB API Token.

Learn more about creating API Tokens here: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/security/tokens/create-token/

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also help me out with a proper Nifi flow for writing data from SQL server to InfluxDB because when I tried the same via Rest API, InfluxDB did not accept the CSV Record or the JSON format data? Please direct me to a correct Nifi flow

Comment: That will vary depending on the structure of your SQL/Json data. But basically the `PutInfluxDatabaseRecord_2` asks for a "Record Reader" controller service to parse the incoming FlowFile content. You can choose `JsonPathReader` or `JsonTreeReader` to consume Json data. `JsonTreeReader` is the simplest if you have a flat json object. Then, in the `PutInfluxDatabaseRecord_2` processor's settings you will just have to identify which json keys should be used as the LineProtocol measurement, fields, tags (optional), and timestamp (optional) from your data. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I followed your advice and it is working for me now.